# UNNotification Local Notification and Do Not Disturb

Tags: ios, localnotification, unnotificationrequest

Sleep Cycle app manages to send a Local Notification and play a sound even when I have 'do not disturb' enabled on my phone.

How do you do this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, one can do by enabling "Critical alert" property in UNNotificationSetting while configuring local notification.

Apple Doc - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationsettings/2963116-criticalalertsetting

> When UNNotificationSetting.enabled, this property authorizes the app
>   to play critical sounds that ignore Do Not Disturb and the device’s
>   mute switch.
>
> For local notifications, the system attempts to play a critical sound
>   when the sound property of the UNNotificationContent object contains
>   an object returned by the defaultCritical property, the
>   criticalSoundNamed(_:) method, or a related method.
>
> For remote notifications, the system attempts to play a critical sound
>   when the notification’s payload contains a sound directory that
>   contains the critical key.
>
> Critical alerts require a special entitlement issued by Apple.