# Swift Local Notifications in Do Not Disturb

Tags: ios, swiftui, unusernotificationcenter

I have a SwiftUI Timer App and I want the user to get notified when the timer runs out. I currently do this with just a local notification.

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = String(localized: "proTimer")
content.body = String(localized: "\(name)IstAbgelaufen")
content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: UNNotificationSoundName("\(sound).wav"))

let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: endDate!.timeIntervalSince(Date.now), repeats: false)
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: id.uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
```

Unfortunately, if the user has enabled Do Not Disturb, this notification will no longer be delivered. What can I do against it? Is there something like "urgent notifications"?

Answer (score 2):

yes, you need to enable "Critical alert" property in UNNotificationSetting while configuring local notification.

Documentation -> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationsettings/2963116-criticalalertsetting

check this link [UNNotification Local Notification and Do Not Disturb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55040319/unnotification-local-notification-and-do-not-disturb)

Comment: Critical alerts could be a bit extreme. There are also [time sensitive](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationinterruptionlevel/timesensitive) notifications; the user can still disable them, but this is their choice.

Answer (score 0):

You could also configure and enable an AVAudioSession and play a sound using AVPlayer. You just need to make sure your app gets its computing power when the time is up.

This would also work on phones with the silence-switch enabled.

The only hacky thing here is to wake the phone and let your sound play.

Instead I'd think an app should look for the Do-Not-Disturb mode and simply warn, if it's enabled.